# Interaction Behaviors and DataTrigger with Storyboard not working

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I am working on a UWP app and I am trying to implement the MVVM methodology. Basically I am trying to run a Storyboard when the value of a Binding changes during run-time.

So far I have come up with the following:

```xml
<UserControl
    ...
    xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:Media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="cValueSB" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3">
            <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="cvalue" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="hValueSB" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3">
            <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="hvalue" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="lValueSB" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3">
            <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="lvalue" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="nValueSB" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3">
            <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="nvalue" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="large">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource ScreenWidthSixForty}"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="cvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Target="hvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Target="lvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Target="nvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Target="cvalue.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Target="hvalue.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Target="lvalue.(Grid.Column)" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Target="nvalue.(Grid.Column)" Value="3"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="middle">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource ScreenWidthThreeSixty}"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="cvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Target="hvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Target="lvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Target="nvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Target="cvalue.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Target="hvalue.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Target="lvalue.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Target="nvalue.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Target="cvalue.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Target="hvalue.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Target="lvalue.(Grid.Column)" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Target="nvalue.(Grid.Column)" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Target="lvalue.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Target="nvalue.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="2"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="mobile">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource ScreenWidthZero}"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="cvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Target="hvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Target="lvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="3"/>
                        <Setter Target="nvalue.(Grid.Row)" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter Target="cvalue.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Target="hvalue.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Target="lvalue.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Target="nvalue.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Target="cvalue.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter Target="hvalue.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter Target="lvalue.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter Target="nvalue.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="4"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
            Style="{StaticResource FlyoutPickerTitleTextBlockStyle}"
            Text="{Binding Symbol, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"/>
        <TextBlock
            Name="cvalue"
            Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding CurrentValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction
                        Storyboard="{StaticResource cValueSB}"
                        ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Run Text="Current value:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding CurrentValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock
            Name="hvalue"
            Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}">
            <Run Text="High value:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding HighValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"/>
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding HighValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction
                        Storyboard="{StaticResource hValueSB}"
                        ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock
            Name="lvalue"
            Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}">
            <Run Text="Low value:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding LowValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"/>
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding LowValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction
                        Storyboard="{StaticResource lValueSB}"
                        ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock
            Name="nvalue"
            Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}">
            <Run Text="Net change:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding NetChangeValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"/>
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding NetChangeValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction
                        Storyboard="{StaticResource lValueSB}"
                        ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The problem that I am facing is that the Animation is not working when the value of the Binding changes. I'd like to avoid any direct code-behind as much as possible unless absolutely necessary. Is this even the right way to do this? I am new to Xaml Behaviors so would like some help in implementing it.

if there is a more refined approach to achieve the above, I'd be happy to know about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTriggerBehavior is triggered when the data the behaviors is bound to meets a specified condition. You just only bind to the property but have not specified any conditions to trigger this behavior.

> Basically I am trying to run a Storyboard when the value of a Binding changes during run-time.

By your requirement, you need to add `ComparisonCondition="NotEqual"`, if you have a fixed value to compare with the bound property value, you could add `Value=xxx`.

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding CurrentValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" ComparisonCondition="NotEqual">
        <Media:ControlStoryboardAction
                    Storyboard="{StaticResource cValueSB}"
                    ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```